# How to include SVG to show on Android Webkit? How to access SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

There are several options on how to include SVG image in HTML: `img` tag, `object` tag, `svg` tag, `embed` tag, `obect` with `svg` inside, namespaced `svg` tag etc.

Do you know what is the syntax that WebKit on Adroit (tablets) will display correctly?

Follow up: Which methods allow the developer to access the SVG-DOM nodes from the outside document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native Android browser doesn’t support SVG. They originally disabled SVG in their branch of WebKit, and it hasn’t been enabled yet.

See [this comment](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1376#c4) in their bug tracker.